# Pass events and handlers as parameters

Tags: vb.net, events

In VB.NET you have the statement:

```
AddHandler object As Event, object As Delegate
```

I need to be able to activate and deactivate handlers at runtime, so I want something akin to this:

```
Class EventHandler
    Private mEvent as Event
    Private mDelegate As Delegate
    Public Sub New(evt As Event, del as Delegate)
        mEvent=evt
        mDeletate=del
    End Sub
    Public Sub Activate
        AddHandler mEvent, Delegate
    End Sub
    Public Sub Deactivate
        RemoveHandler mEvent, Delegate
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not impossible.  A simple Boolean property "IgnoreEvent" that's tested in the event handler is far simpler and *much* less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Hans. The pseudo-code I provided is actually a simplification of my scenario, in order to avoid suggestions that solve the wrong problem. What I'm looking for is an answer to the question of whether it is possible to implement a solution along the lines that my pseudo-code suggests.

Comment: Never mind. I came up with something using reflection.